# How to use <%= %> in linkbutton?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.0

I am trying to make this code work but it won't:

```
<asp:LinkButton OnClick="lnkSub_Click" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;"
                                Text="Process Payment" ID="lnkSub" OnClientClick="processing(this,'<%=lnkDel.ClientID%>','<%=spPrPyt.ClientID%>');" />
```

How do I make `<%= %>` work inside server control?

Comment: Are you getting any error? Code seems fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this trick.

Used to work for me (notice `#`)

```
<asp:LinkButton OnClick="lnkSub_Click" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;"
                                Text="Process Payment" ID="lnkSub" OnClientClick="processing(this,'<%#lnkDel.ClientID%>','<%#spPrPyt.ClientID%>');" />
```

And in `pre_render` do :

`Page.DataBind();` (or `this.DataBind()`)

Answer (score 2):

From code behind inside `PreRender` event

```
lnkSub_Click.OnClientClick = "processing(this,'" +lnkDel.ClientID +"','"+spPrPyt.ClientID+"');";
```

Comment: most easy solution. Doing in code behin. I used this one only :)